# pulsate not working on each div

Tags: jquery, html

i got a quick question. It's probably something very easy that I've missed. But when I click the div, it pulsates all, when i want to do one individually.

http://jsfiddle.net/v36MT/

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {  
            $("#toggle").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().effect("pulsate", { times:2 }).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
        </script>
```

See what I'm saying?

Comment: IDs must be unique and here you shouldn't target the parent http://jsfiddle.net/v36MT/2/

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute is kind of unique thing. So sticking on to standards, JQuery selects the first matched element if your selector is and ID. If you want multiple elements to be bound to a same event handler, go for a class based approach.

In the updated fiddle, at http://jsfiddle.net/v36MT/5/ I have implemented it. It will cause each element to pulsate two times and when the animation is complete, it fades away. The Jquery snippet is as follows. See the fiddle to see it in action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".toggler").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $(this).effect('pulsate',{times:2},function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    });
});
```